# How do I Upload more images per tweet with Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I would like to upload more than one pic per tweet on Twitter.
I was able to make it work for one image but when i tried to upload more pics then problems popped up. I tried to implement other solutions I have seen in the internet but without success. Maybe it is also because I have just started studying Python and cannot understand errors properly.

This is what I have written:

```
# auth on tw
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, APP_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# create API obj
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# create tweet
tweet = "Test with imgs"
pics = ["ninja.jpg", "ninja2.jpg"]
media_ids = [api.media_upload(i).media_id_string for i in pics]

status = api.update_status_with_media(filename = media_ids, status = tweet)
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bog/2test.py", line 31, in <module>
    status = api.update_status_with_media(filename = media_ids, status = tweet)
  File "/home/bog/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bog/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 1181, in update_status_with_media
    files = {'media[]': stack.enter_context(open(filename, 'rb'))}
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Edit:
I have also tried the following code:

```
# create tweet
tweet = "Test con img"
pics = ["ninja.jpg", "ninja2.jpg"]
media_ids = []
for pic in pics:
    res = api.media_upload(pic)
    media_ids.append(res.media_id)

status = api.update_status_with_media(media_ids = media_ids, status = tweet)
print(media_ids)
```

and I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bog/2test.py", line 34, in <module>
    status = api.update_status_with_media(media_ids = media_ids, status = tweet)
  File "/home/bog/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: update_status_with_media() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `update_status_with_media()`. It's deprecated and doesn't accept `media_ids` as a parameter anyways. Use `update_status()` and pass in a list of `media_id_string`.

This should work:
`status = api.update_status(media_ids = media_ids, status = tweet)`

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.update_status